# How do I select all classes greater than a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose I have the following:

```
<div class="d1">.</div><br>
<div class="d2">.</div><br>
<div class="d3">.</div><br>
<div class="d4">.</div><br>
<div class="d5">.</div><br>
<div class="d6">.</div><br>
<div class="d7">.</div><br>
<div class="d8">.</div><br>
<div class="d9">.</div><br>
<div class="d10">.</div><br>
```

Is there a selector that will grab all divs of, say, d3 through d7?

**[You can fiddle around with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nc5e8/)**

Keep in mind that they may not be in order in the DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to extract the numbers from the class names and [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to restrict the set of elements to the subset you want:

```
var divs = $("div").filter(function() {
    var number = parseInt(this.className.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
    return (number >= 3 && number <= 7);
});
```

Comment: I see, btw you don't need the `parseInt`, and you don't need to use jQuery to get the `className`

Comment: @qwertymk, you're right about `className` (answer updated, thanks), but `parseInt()` should still be called because `match()` returns a string, right? :)

Comment: I usually don't as js isn't that strict, also because when you compare it to numbers it'll cast it for you. Also if you are going to cast it then either supply a radix or use the `+` conversion hack thingy

Comment: `match()` returns either a result array or null. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: @DigitalPlane: good call, you need to add `[0]` after the `.match(/\d+/)`

Comment: You need to do `var number = parseInt(this.className.match(/\d+/)[0]);` because match returns an array.

Comment: @qwertymk, good point about the radix, answer updated. It still prefer calling `parseInt()` rather than relying on automatic conversion, though :)

Comment: Also, you need to be careful about `match()` returning `null`, as then `var number = parseInt(this.className.match(/\d+/)[0]);` would throw an exception.

Comment: @Digital, @Zanfa, strange, it seems to return a string in my case: `"f1".match(/\d+/) == 1` is `true` in my tests.

Comment: What the reason to use regexp here? Can be done with `var number = className.substr(1)` only.

Comment: @bjornd, that's more flexible if the class name prefix changes :)

Comment: But less flexible if numeric prefix will be added.

Comment: Javascript is not too strict and 'a' == ['a'], but it would still be appropriate (better readability) if you had the [0], since it gives more information about the original object.

Comment: @Zanfa, you're right, I wasn't aware Javascript collapsed single-item arrays in this manner. Answer updated, thanks to you and Digital Plane :)

Comment: Just for future reference, JS does array.join(',') if you compare it with a string to get the stringified representation of it. So ['a', 'b'] == 'a,b' is true.

Comment: @Zanfa: Actually, it just calls the `toString()` method of the object (which in case of an array has the same effect as `arr.join(',')` by default)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this.

```
$('*[class^="d"]').each(function() {
    var number = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/\d+/));
    if(number >= 3 && number <= 7){
        $(this).html("Match");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shaneburgess/nc5e8/15/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(function() {

    var greaterThan = 4;
    var smallerThan = 8;

    $('div').each(function(i, e) {
        if (i > greaterThan && i< smallerThan) $(e).css('background-color', '#ffcc00');
    });

});
```

Comment: No need for `.each`, you can pass a function to [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) directly. Just don't return anything (or return `undefined`) for the elements you don't want to change. (This isn't called out in the `css` docs, but it works the same way `attr` does, and the behavior is called out there.)

Answer (score 0):

This will get the range you want:

```
 $('div').slice(2,7).css('background','red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/nc5e8/8/

If you just want greater than, you can do this

```
 $('div:gt(3)').css('background','red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/nc5e8/13/

Comment: You are assuming that there is a trivial correspondence between numbers in classnames and the order in the DOM tree. And you are right, it's logical. Nevertheless, generally speaking, we can have some set numbered differently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you always can create specific css selector, say:

```
$(specificSelector("div.d", 10, 20))
```

where

```
specificSelector = function(pref, from, to) {
    var cnames = []
    for (var j = from; j < to; j++) {
        cnames.push(pref + String(j))
    }
    return cnames.join(",")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate selector: http://jsfiddle.net/nnZ79/

```
var start = 3, 
    stop = 7,
    selector = [];

for (; start <= stop; start++) {
    selector.push('.d'+start);
}

$(selector.join(',')).css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) methods and you may use the gt and lt for your specific search or any regex for making search more specific